# Web3 how to create a script that notifies me if there is a new transaction from a specific contract

Tags: javascript, web3js

new to web3.js and want to know the libraries that are useful in building scripts for monitoring contracts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moralis. It has a function "Sync And watch contract events" and "Sync and Watch Address". You can create for example a bot which will send you info in telegram using Moralis Cloud Code.

Take a look at [docs](https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/automatic-transaction-sync/historical-transactions)